# issuing things to shell and forgetting about it in php

Tags: php

how do you issue commands to the shell and then forget it's output and such? for example:

```
<?php
echo `sleep 2;echo hi`;
echo "foo";
?>
```

the result for this is hifoo. i would want a result that gives me foohi. why? i want the command issued to the shell simply issued and forgotten, i am confused about why PHP will wait for the result. is such a result possible?

(the idea behind this is setting up the correct number of selenium grid RC instances programatically. currently, it will stop after the first process is opened)

Comment: You fork a process and kill the parent process, making effectively a daemon. Just make sure it exits after it's done doing its thing.

Comment: @N.B.: Note the need to close the standard file descriptors in order to get the parent to exit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From php.net exec()

> If a program is started with this
>   function, in order for it to continue
>   running in the background, the output
>   of the program must be redirected to a
>   file or another output stream. Failing
>   to do so will cause PHP to hang until
>   the execution of the program ends.

The same applies for all shell commands.

Comment: how would i do that in the given example? `sleep 2;echo hi > tmp.txt` is what i am guessing but doesn't do it.

Comment: Needs to be backgrounded to, `... &` - all outputs need to be redirected, `STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR`.

Answer (score 0):

It's like anything you do at the command prompt, unless you take measures to put the new command in the background, the shell (and PHP ) will block until the command exits. Try this:

```
<?php
echo `(sleep 2; echo hi) &`;
echo 'foo';
?>
```

Note the brackets around your command, without that, the `&` woulud apply only to the echo , and you'd still have the 2 second pause.